# When i refresh a VueJS page with opened modale i loose CSS style

Tags: css, vue.js, refresh

I have a little problem, a little "classic" question, but I can't find an answer to this one...

Let me explain. When I have a page with a modal component, and when I just want to refresh the page of my browser, the page refreshes but I lose all my style...

Could you explain why?

Before refreshing

[image]

After refreshment

[image]

Regards,
Christophe

Comment: Not sure why you are refreshing the browser.  Generally with a browser refresh the Vue application is re-initialized, so it may have something to do with the fact that your modal is already open and not being opened normally after the Vue re-init.

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for your answer. Well in fact you're right, i don't need to do a refresh, but if a user do it by mistake i don't want that my users see a broken website ^^'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, the problem was with the css call on public/index.html

Not working

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
```

Working

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css">
```